# what does "this" mean in WebView component at props "ref" in react native webview

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

i try to injectJavaScript in react native web view like bellow work well

```
setTimeout(() => {
 this.webref.injectJavaScript(someJSCODE); 
}, 3000);
<WebView
ref={r => this.webref = r}
source={{uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/'}}
 />
```

but if i call r.injectJavaScript(someCode) it not working.

```
<WebView
ref={r => r.injectJavaScript(somecode)}
source={{uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/'}}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following ,

```
...
<WebView
        source={{
          uri: "https://************.org/privacy-policy/"
        }}
        ref={WEBVIEW_REF => (this.WebViewRef = WEBVIEW_REF)}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        injectedJavaScript={
          "document.getElementsByClassName('site-content')[0].style.paddingTop='0px',document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.display='none', document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0].style.display='none',document.getElementsByClassName('subscribe-line')[0].style.display='none'"
        }
        onLoadProgress={e => this._onLoading(e.nativeEvent.progress)}
      />
...
```